# How to find all commits (revision numbers) in which a file was deleted/moved in SVN

Tags: svn, svnadmin, collabnet

I need to find all deleted files from SVN. Then check if file needs a restoration after going through it. If yes then restore. How do I do that. I know I can restore a deleted file but that needs revision numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`svn log --search`](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#svn-log-search) (available since SVN 1.8) to look up the revision where the particular file was deleted and then restore it.

The following command will find revisions where `MyProject/MyForm.cs` file was deleted.

```
svn log -v --search "MyProject/MyForm.cs" --search-and "D" http://svn.example.com/svn/MyRepository
```

I don't see description of the new `--search` argument in SVNBook so including command-line help for your reference (check `svn help log` for more information):

```
 If the --search option is used, log messages are displayed only if the
 provided search pattern matches any of the author, date, log message
 text (unless --quiet is used), or, if the --verbose option is also
 provided, a changed path.
 The search pattern may include "glob syntax" wildcards:
     ?      matches any single character
     *      matches a sequence of arbitrary characters
     [abc]  matches any of the characters listed inside the brackets
 If multiple --search options are provided, a log message is shown if
 it matches any of the provided search patterns. If the --search-and
 option is used, that option's argument is combined with the pattern
 from the previous --search or --search-and option, and a log message
 is shown only if it matches the combined search pattern.
 If --limit is used in combination with --search, --limit restricts the
 number of log messages searched, rather than restricting the output
 to a particular number of matching log messages.
```